# How to get JSF composite components to work in WebView

Tags: java, android, jsf-2, composite-component

I have JSF 2.1 web application with Spring and Hibernate.
I need to create an Android vesion of that web application. I did it with help of WebView. Everything is OK. Enabling JavaScript and navigating web page history. However, JSF composite components are not working. They work fine in regular browsers.

How to get JSF composite components to work in Android application using WebView?

**EDIT** : I use composite component in many places in my application for example I had one component for see more "list items with see more link"

here's the code for the component

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="from" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="to" required="true" shortDescription="First time limit before clicking see more link"/>
    <cc:attribute name="moreSize" required="true"  shortDescription="Limit when clicking see more link"/>
    <cc:attribute name="totalCount" required="false" shortDescription="Total counts that helps is displaying see more link or not"/>

</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <div class="SeeMore" from="#{cc.attrs.from}" to="#{cc.attrs.to}" moresize="#{cc.attrs.moreSize}" totalcount="#{cc.attrs.totalCount}"></div>
</cc:implementation>
```

and I used it by

```
<core:seeMore moreSize="10" totalcount="20" from="0" to="10"/>
```

when I view any page that had core:seeMore using android webView it doesn't list anything at all.

Comment: Please describe "not working" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective.

Comment: I hope I described as developer's perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer after 3 Long days.

the problem was all composite components that I have have this code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

which conflict with android webview and doesn't work with jquery selectors ... Don't know why!!!

but when I removed the above code from the composite components. the web application in android webview works fine.